# Lucene near words suggestion

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a 300GB size index for about 4 million text documents. It is what I try to accomplish:

Step 1: search for a word or phrase.  Say 1000 documents are found.

Step 2: identify the most common words and phrases in the search results, i.e. the 1000 documents.  The "most common words and phrases" should be with a X distance from the word or phrase being searched in Step 1. X distance can be any number from 1 word distance to 1000 word distance.

Step 3. use the "most common words and phrases" found to search again for documents among the 4 million documents.

I read questions about auto-suggestion and ngram search in Luncene.  But still do not know how to do it optimally, especially should I use a special analyzer,a special query or both?

Answer (score 0):

I've used a special pre-analyzer (indexing each n-gram as a phrase) with good effect (see the [RELMA LOINC](http://loinc.org/relma) medical term search/mapping program).